# Наследование от функции

Tags: javascript, наследование, ecmascript-6

ES6 позволяет наследоваться от особых объектов. Получается унаследоваться и от функции. Получившийся объект можно вызывать как функцию. Но как сделать, чтобы при вызове происходило что-то отличное от вызова пустой функции?

```
class Smth extends Function {
  // Что здесь сделать
}

(new Smth)() // чтобы тут вернулось не undefined?
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/4928642)

Comment: можно ничего не писать :-) это ж функция: `var s = new Smth("a","return a+10;")` и тогда `s(10)` вернет -> 20

Comment: @Grundy, внимательнее. `var s = new Smth; s() /* этот вызов должен вернуть */`

Comment: @Grundy, а, всё. До меня дошло, что ты имел в виду. Ты прав. Но это несколько не то, чего хотелось бы. Есть возможность внутри класса разместить код не в виде строки? Со строкой я понял - можешь ответом написать.

Comment: @Grundy, хотя нет, там не очень получается - общая конструкция - да, но что-то туда передать - нет. `class Smth extends Function {
  constructor (x) {
    super('t', 'return t + this.x');
    this.x = x;
  }
}

(new Smth(90))(1)`

Comment: ты просто рассматривай `Smth` не как функцию, а как конструктор который функцию возвращает, и работает он так же как Function

Comment: @Grundy, мне хочется чтобы он был как нормальный объект, но его можно было вызывать скобочками как функцию. Получится из него такую штуковину сделать?

Comment: Тут надо подумать :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38918/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-grundy).

Comment: @vas, вопрос на английском подробнее. Когда я разберусь с тамошними ответами детальнее, дополню вопрос и приведу на него ответ.

Comment: @vas посмотрите такую библиотеку как `knockout.js`. Иногда чесать нос через... заднее место бывает удобно :)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/4928642

Answer (score 2):

Взяв в качестве базового [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/4340086), я немного его доработал и вот что получилось.

Дорабатывал я две вещи. Во-первых, передавать функцию в конструктор базового класса - не самое красивое решение; потому я переадресую реальный вызов методу `call`. Обычно этот метод вызывает основную функцию - но у меня получилось наоборот (сигнатура удачно совпала).

Во-вторых, надо обеспечить адекватное значение для `this` (желательно чтобы это был сам объект-функция, потому что IDE будет думать к контекстных подсказках именно так). При этом надо не потерять реальный `this` (я его передаю первым аргументом).

Ну и плюс надо убрать не имеющую смысла информацию из вывода `toString()` - никому не интересно видеть там замыкание вида "взять аргументы и передать дальше".

Получилось вот так:

```
class ExtendableFunction extends Function {
    constructor() {
        super()
        function f(...args) {
            return f.call(this, ...args);
        }
        Object.setPrototypeOf(f, this.constructor.prototype);
        return f
    }

    call(context, ...args) {
        throw "Not implemented"
    }

    toString() {
        return this.constructor.name + "(...)";
    }
};

class HelloWorld extends ExtendableFunction {
    call() {
        console.log("Hello, world!", this, arguments)
    }
};
```

Но мое чувство прекрасного все еще не радо. Вспомните, как часто вы делали обертки над функциями, которые вызывают вложенную функцию через `apply`. Или как часто вы `bind`или функцию к объекту... Теперь во всех этих цепочках будет на 1 обертку больше - ведь эти методы будут применяться сначала к `f` - а потом уже к `call`.

Наконец, если мы *уже* пишем функтор-обертку, то, вероятно, нам будет проще определять для него не метод `call` - а метод `apply`. Поэтому в финальной версии я "спрямил" метод `bind`, а методы `call` и `apply` сделал по умолчанию вызывающими друг друга - чтобы наследник мог переопределить любого.

```
class ExtendableFunction extends Function {
    constructor() {
        super()
        function f(...args) {
            return f.call(this, ...args);
        }
        Object.setPrototypeOf(f, this.constructor.prototype);
        return f
    }

    call(context, ...args) {
        return this.apply(context, args)
    }

    apply(context, args) {
        return this.call(context, ...args)
    }

    bind(context, ...args) {
        return this.call.bind(this, context, ...args)
    }

    toString() {
        return this.constructor.name + "(...)";
    }
};

class HelloWorld extends ExtendableFunction {
    call(context, ..args) {
        console.log("Hello, world!", this, context, args)
    }
};

class HelloWorld2 extends ExtendableFunction {
    apply(context, args) {
        console.log("Hello, world!", this, context, args)
    }
};
```

Comment: Я собирался проверить решения из ответов детальнее, затем разместить ответ тут.

Comment: `unshift.call(arguments` - это же плохо?

Comment: Чем плохо? Оптимизации она в строгом режиме не выключает. В любом случае, я от нее уже избавился.

Comment: А что за финт с `this` - он разве не будет в данном случае всегда _undefined_ - я имею ввиду тот который первым аргументом передается

Comment: Почему же? `var obj = { h: new HelloWorld() }` Теперь если вызвать `obj.h()` - то `this` (который первым аргументом идет) будет `obj`. Все как у обычных функций.

Comment: @Grundy не говоря уже о том что всегда можно вызвать `call` или `apply`...

Comment: да, запутался с функциями принимаемыми подменяемыми и т.д.:)

Comment: **Обновил ответ.**